# View is not accessible after ParentViewController.View.AddSubview

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using Monotouch to develop iPad app.

Here is my scenario:

I Created Tabbed base application. 
e.g. Home, Admin, Reports....etc
Home tab is UIViewController.

I want three section inside Home Tab:
e.g. Category(Table view with navigation control (reason to use navigation because we have subcategories inside Category) beside Category Table, Items of selected category(Other Table view) and right hand side is detail view of Selected ITEM.

Here is what i did....

Dynamically create two tableview controller and added to main view controller.

HomeViewController.cs:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

         RootViewController rvc = new RootViewController("",UITableViewStyle.Grouped);

        // navigation controller will manage the views displayed and provide navigation buttons
        navigationController = new UINavigationController();
        navigationController.PushViewController(rvc, false);
        navigationController.TopViewController.Title ="Category";

        navigationController.View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 50, (50), (600));



        // Main window to which we add the navigation controller to
         this.View.AddSubview(navigationController.View);

        itemtable.Delegate = new TableViewDelegate (list);
        itemtable.DataSource = new TableViewDataSource (list);

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

=====================================================

RootViewController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Drawing;

namespace DVPNTN_MobileApp
{
[MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("RootViewController")]
public partial class RootViewController : UITableViewController
{
    public List<string> RootData = new List<string> { "Group1", "Group2" };
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UINavigationController navigationControllerItem;
    string SelectedGroup;

    // Allow us to set the style of the TableView
    public RootViewController(string selectedGroup, UITableViewStyle style) : base(style)
    {
        this.SelectedGroup = selectedGroup; 
    }


    class DataSource : UITableViewDataSource
    {
        static NSString kCellIdentifier = new NSString ("MyIdentifier");
        RootViewController tvc;

        public DataSource (RootViewController tvc)
        {
            this.tvc = tvc;
        }

        public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableView, int section)
        {
            return tvc.RootData.Count;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (kCellIdentifier);

            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, kCellIdentifier);
            }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = tvc.RootData.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
            return cell;
        }
    }

    class TableDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
    {
        RootViewController tvc;
        SubGroupViewController sgvc;

        public TableDelegate (RootViewController tvc)
        {
            this.tvc = tvc;
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            string selectedGroup = tvc.RootData.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);

            sgvc = new SubGroupViewController(selectedGroup, UITableViewStyle.Grouped);

            tvc.NavigationController.PushViewController(sgvc,true);
            //tvc.View.RemoveFromSuperview();
            //tvc.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        TableView.Delegate = new TableDelegate (this);
        TableView.DataSource = new DataSource (this);


        RootVIewItemController rvc1 = new RootVIewItemController(SelectedGroup,UITableViewStyle.Grouped);

        // navigation controller will manage the views displayed and provide navigation buttons
        navigationControllerItem = new UINavigationController();

        navigationControllerItem.PushViewController(rvc1, false);
        navigationControllerItem.TopViewController.Title = SelectedGroup + " " + "Item List";


            navigationControllerItem.View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 300, (50),(700));

         //this.View.AddSubview(navigationControllerItem.View);
        //rvc1.View.EnableInputClicksWhenVisible = true;

        //this.ParentViewController.AddChildViewController(navigationControllerItem);
**> Problem is here --- subview is successfully added to parent view but it's not accessible, mean items are there but we can't touch cell or row???????**
        ParentViewController.View.AddSubview(navigationControllerItem.View);




        GC.Collect();
    }
    public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        // Return true for supported orientations
        return true;

    }


}
```

}

**************** ItemViewController  ********

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace DVPNTN_MobileApp
{
[MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("RootVIewItemController")]
public partial class RootVIewItemController : UITableViewController
{

    public List<string> RootData = new List<string> { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" };
    string SelectedGroup;

    public RootVIewItemController (string selectedGroup, UITableViewStyle style) : base (style)
    {
        this.SelectedGroup = selectedGroup; 
    }


    class DataSource : UITableViewDataSource
    {
        static NSString kCellIdentifier = new NSString ("MyIdentifier");
        RootVIewItemController tvc;

        public DataSource (RootVIewItemController tvc)
        {
            this.tvc = tvc;
        }

        public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableView, int section)
        {
            return tvc.RootData.Count;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (kCellIdentifier);

            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, kCellIdentifier);
            }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = tvc.RootData.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
            //cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;

            return cell;
        }
    }

    class TableDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
    {
        RootVIewItemController tvc;
        SubGroupViewController sgvc;

        public TableDelegate (RootVIewItemController tvc)
        {
            this.tvc = tvc;
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            string selectedGroup = tvc.RootData.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
            Console.WriteLine(
                "TableViewDelegate.RowSelected: Label={0}",selectedGroup);

            /*
            if(sgvc == null)
                sgvc = new SubGroupViewController(selectedGroup, UITableViewStyle.Grouped);

            tvc.NavigationController.PushViewController(sgvc,true);*/
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        TableView.Delegate = new TableDelegate (this);
        TableView.DataSource = new DataSource (this);
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```

}

---

Question:

- Is it right way to doing this scenario?
- It's work fine but when we add Item view to parent view controller it is not accessible, mean item list are there but cells are not accessible, we can't touch cell and raise even or  do scrolling.

Please anybody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Your cells' frames are 10x10 (cell.Frame = new RectangleF(0,0,10,10);), that's why there is probably no interaction. The content is overflowing (visible) but cannot be interacted with.

Comment: Thanks for reply... even i remove cell.frame it's same behaviour.. however cell.frame is in Rootviewcontroller and problem is when i am trying to create new tableviewcontroller inside root view controller...   ParentViewController.View.AddSubview(navigationControllerItem.View);

Answer (score 4):

I am not completely sure what you wanted to do.  I took my best guess and created a sample with two solutions.  One solution per tab.  The first uses the built-in split view controller.  I have read several places the UISplitViewController must be the root of the application.  I have broke that rule by adding it as a child of the tab control.

The second creates a custom version of a split control.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Drawing;

namespace delete04223
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow window;
        UITabBarController tabBarController;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // create a new window instance based on the screen size
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            var viewController1 = new MyUISplitViewController ();
            var viewController2 = new MyUISplitViewController2 ();
            tabBarController = new UITabBarController ();
            tabBarController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController [] {
                viewController1,
                viewController2,
            };

            window.RootViewController = tabBarController;
            // make the window visible
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class MyUISplitViewController : UISplitViewController
    {
        public MyUISplitViewController ()
        {
            this.Title = "Native Split View";
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            var viewController1 = new LeftViewController ();
            var viewController2 = new DummyViewController ("Pane 1", "Pane 1");
            this.ViewControllers = new UIViewController [] {viewController1, viewController2};
            this.WeakDelegate = viewController2;

        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class MyUISplitViewController2 : UIViewController
    {
        public MyUISplitViewController2 ()
        {
            this.Title = "Custom Split View";
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            var viewController1 = new LeftViewController ();
            var viewController2 = new DummyViewController ("Pane 1", "Pane 1");

            this.AddChildViewController (viewController1);
            this.AddChildViewController (viewController2);

            this.View.AddSubview (viewController1.View);
            this.View.AddSubview (viewController2.View);
        }

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews ();

            RectangleF lRect = this.View.Frame;
            RectangleF rRect = lRect;

            lRect.Width = .3f * lRect.Width;
            rRect.X = lRect.Width + 1;
            rRect.Width = (.7f * rRect.Width)-1;

            this.View.Subviews[0].Frame = lRect;
            this.View.Subviews[1].Frame = rRect;
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class LeftViewController : UINavigationController
    {
        public LeftViewController ()
        {

        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();    

            MyUITableViewController table = new MyUITableViewController (this);

            this.PushViewController (table, false);
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override UIViewController PopViewControllerAnimated (bool animated)
        {
            return base.PopViewControllerAnimated (true);
        }
    }

    public class DummyViewController : UIViewController
    {
        string _myLabelText = "";
        UIToolbar _toolbar;


        public DummyViewController (string viewName, string labelText)
        {
            this.Title = viewName;  
            this._myLabelText = labelText;
            this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            float center = this.View.Frame.Width / 2f;
            UILabel label = new UILabel (new RectangleF (center - 50, 100, 100, 40));
            label.Text = this._myLabelText;
            label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            label.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleMargins;

            RectangleF rect = this.View.Frame;
            rect.Y = 0;
            rect.Height = 44;
            _toolbar = new UIToolbar (rect);
            _toolbar.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;

            this.View.AddSubview (label);
            this.View.AddSubview (_toolbar);
        }

        [Export("splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:")]
        public void WillHideViewController (UISplitViewController svc, UIViewController vc,
            UIBarButtonItem barButtonItem, UIPopoverController pc)
        {
            barButtonItem.Title = "Menu";
            var items = new List<UIBarButtonItem> ();
            items.Add (barButtonItem);
            if (_toolbar.Items != null) 
                items.AddRange (_toolbar.Items);
            _toolbar.SetItems (items.ToArray (), true);
            //popoverController = pc;
        }

        [Export("splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:")]
        public void WillShowViewController (UISplitViewController svc, UIViewController vc,
            UIBarButtonItem button)
        {
            // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
            var items = new List<UIBarButtonItem> (_toolbar.Items);
            items.RemoveAt (0);
            _toolbar.SetItems (items.ToArray (), true);
            //popoverController = null;
        }
    }

    internal class MyUITableViewController : UITableViewController
    {
        static NSString kCellIdentifier = new NSString ("MyIdentifier");
        LeftViewController _parent;

        public MyUITableViewController (LeftViewController parent) : base (UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        {
            this.TableView.WeakDelegate = this;
            this.TableView.WeakDataSource = this;
            this._parent = parent;
        }

        [Export ("tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:")]
        public int RowsInSection (UITableView tableView, int section)
        {
            if (section == 0)
                return 2;

            return 3;
        }

        [Export ("tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (kCellIdentifier);

            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, kCellIdentifier);
            }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = GetRowName (indexPath);

            return cell;
        }

        private string GetRowName (NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            string ret;
            if (indexPath.Section == 0)
            {
                ret = 
                    indexPath.Row == 0 ? "Row A" : "Row B";
            }
            else
            {
                ret = 
                    indexPath.Row == 0 ? "Row D" : 
                        indexPath.Row == 1 ? "Row E" : "Row F"; 
            }   

            return ret;
        }

        [Export ("numberOfSectionsInTableView:")]
        public int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 2;
        }

        [Export ("tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:")]
        public string TitleForHeader (UITableView tableView, int section)
        {
            if (section == 0)
                return "One";

            return "Two";
        }

        [Export ("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public virtual void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item Selected: Section={0}, Row={1}",indexPath.Section, indexPath.Row);  
            this._parent.PushViewController (new MySubUITableViewController (), true);
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    internal class MySubUITableViewController : UITableViewController
    {
        static NSString kCellIdentifier = new NSString ("MyIdentifier");
        static string [] _names = new string [] {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

        public MySubUITableViewController () : base (UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        {
            this.TableView.WeakDelegate = this;
            this.TableView.WeakDataSource = this;
        }

        [Export ("tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:")]
        public int RowsInSection (UITableView tableView, int section)
        {
            return 5;
        }

        [Export ("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public virtual void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item Selected: Section={0}, Row={1}",indexPath.Section, indexPath.Row);  
        }

        [Export ("tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {

            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (kCellIdentifier);

            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, kCellIdentifier);
            }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = _names[indexPath.Row];

            return cell;
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```